Nodemailer Error: "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful" for Microsoft 365 Outlook via GoDaddy Domain
I’m working on a website built with Next.js (v14), and I’m updating the contact form logic to send emails via a Microsoft 365 Outlook account linked to a domain managed by GoDaddy. The website is hosted on Vercel, and email sending is managed via Nodemailer.
Everything with the email address itself works fine (I can send and receive emails normally), but when I try to integrate the new contact email address into the form submission process, I keep encountering the following error:
Error in the process: Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. 
Code used for sending emails:
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import Mail from "nodemailer/lib/mailer";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { email, name, text } = await request.json();
    console.log("Received request data:", { email, name, text });
    console.log("EMAIL_USER:", process.env.EMAIL_USER);
    console.log("EMAIL_PASS:", process.env.EMAIL_PASS);

    if (!email || !name || !text) {
      throw new Error("Missing required fields");
    }

    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.office365.com",
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USER, // Outlook email
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS, // App password
      },
    });

    const mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      to: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      subject: `Message from ${name} (${email})`,
      text: text,
    };

    await transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Email sent" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error in the process:", err);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: err }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

Environment:

Domain: Managed via GoDaddy (linked to Microsoft 365 Outlook).
Hosting: Website hosted on Vercel.
Email account: MFA-enabled, using App Password for SMTP login.

Question:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with GoDaddy’s Microsoft 365 Outlook and Nodemailer integration? Is there something I’m missing in the authentication setup? Could the issue be related to the Vercel setup or a configuration in the Microsoft 365 tenant?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!
What I’ve tried:

The email account is set up with Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA), so I generated an App Password for Nodemailer authentication.
I’ve triple-checked the credentials (email and App Password), and they are correct.
SMTP Authentication has been enabled for the account.
I’ve disabled Security Defaults for the organization to allow SMTP.
DNS records for SPF, DKIM, and DMARC are correctly configured for email deliverability.

Despite these efforts, I still encounter the authentication error.
